# How to append a text to a file in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to append text to a file in a `Jenkinsfile` injecting the Jenkins `BUILD_ID`

I wish to see:

```
version := "1.0.25"
```

where 25 is the `BUILD_ID`

Here is my attempt:

```
import hudson.EnvVars

node {

  stage('versioning'){
    echo 'retrieve build version'
    sh 'echo version := 1.0.${env.BUILD_ID} >> build.sbt'
  } 
}
```

Error:

> version:=1.0.${env.BUILD_ID}: bad substitution

Note the file is in the current directory

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`env.BUILD_ID` is a groovy variable, not a shell variable. Since you used single-quotes (`'`) groovy will *not* substitute the variables in your string and the shell doesn't know about `${env.BUILD_ID}`. You need to either use double-quotes `"` and let groovy do the substitution

```
sh "echo version := 1.0.${env.BUILD_ID} >> build.sbt"
```

or use the variable the shell knows

```
sh 'echo version := 1.0.$BUILD_ID >> build.sbt'
```

and since you need the version surrounded with doublequotes, you'd need something like this:

```
sh "echo version := \\\"1.0.${env.BUILD_ID}\\\" >> build.sbt"
```

Comment: I have modified my question. Could you please help me in wrapping the code with double apostrophes `version := "1.0.25"`

Comment: for this : sh "echo version := \\\"1.0.${env.BUILD_ID}\\\" >> build.sbt", if the variable (any variable) have single quotes '' and you want to add double quotes and echo that to a file : just like this : " 'hello' " to the file, how this is possible ?

Comment: @tkausl I am using                              ``` sh "echo ${params.project_name}-${params.environment}-${env."${i}_prefix"}-${j} target_fs = ${params."${i}_FS_TYPE"} percentage_fs = ${params."${i}_fs_percentage"} >> ${WORKSPACE}/inventories/hosts"```, but it is not printing to my file. any idea?

Answer (score 34):

The pipeline built in [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) is also very useful here but requires a read+write process to append to a file.

```
def readContent = readFile 'build.sbt'
writeFile file: 'build.sbt', text: readContent+"\r\nversion := 1.0.${env.BUILD_ID}"
```

Answer (score 6):

I've used dirty little wrapper function to implement Stefan Crain's answer above:

```
def appendFile(String fileName, String line) {
    def current = ""
    if (fileExists(fileName)) {
        current = readFile fileName
    }
    writeFile file: fileName, text: current + "\n" + line
}
```

I really don't like it, but it does the trick and it gets round escaping quotes via slashy strings,e.g.:

```
def tempFile = '/tmp/temp.txt'
writeFile file: tempFile, text: "worthless line 1\n"
// now append the string 'version="1.2.3"  # added by appendFile\n' to tempFile
appendFile(tempFile,/version="1.2.3" # added by appendFile/ + "\n")
```

Comment: This solution is more portable that the most voted one...