# Unable to Create New file in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create New file in Jenkins Pipeline , by getting error. 
error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline-Groovy/test.txt (No such file or directory)

But when i am executing below commands without pipeline , It's created new file

```
def newFile = new File("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/test.txt")
newFile.append("hello\n")
println newFile.text
```

If i use same code in Pipeline getting above error

```
pipeline {

    agent any


    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))

        timestamps()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Demo1-stage') {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
                    script {

                        def Jobname = "${JOB_NAME}"
                        echo Jobname
                    }
            }
        }
        stage('Demo-2stage') {
            steps {
                script {

                    def workspace = "${WORKSPACE}"
                    echo workspace
                    def newFile = new File("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline-Groovy/test.txt")
                    newFile.createNewFile() 
                    sh 'ls -lrt'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your path exists? Why not use the ${WORKSPACE} instead of the hardcoded absolute path ?

Comment: Yes, We can use workspace . But for testing purposes hardcoded the path only. But when I am executing same command in Jenkins pipeline getting that error. Path is available.

Comment: Honestly, if you are doing this directly in the pipeline stages and not within library code, you would probably benefit from just using the intrinsic `writeFile` instead of writing your own code for the same functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can not create file via Groovy code(or java code) in jenkinsfile of a pipeline job on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784194/can-not-create-file-via-groovy-codeor-java-code-in-jenkinsfile-of-a-pipeline-j)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your folder is not present. Do not give absolute path while creating the file unless it is a requirement. I see that in your case, you need a file in workspace. Always use the `${WORKSPACE}` to get the current work directory.

```
def newFile = new File("${WORKSPACE}/test.txt")
newFile.createNewFile()
```

Comment: If I use execute same in " build with groovy " it's working, but same command not working in Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: tried with Pipeline, but no luck. getting error : java.io.IOException: No such file or directory     ---- And same working "executing with Groovy Freestyle" Job. I am confused why the same script is not working in Pipeline.

Comment: Can you check if there is any pending inprocess script approval. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/