# How to read a workspace file from within Jenkins Shared Library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline, it imports a shared library which in turn "grabs" a dependency. I want to call a method on the class which takes a File parameter.

**But the file doesn't exist when I try to access it in the shared library.**

### The Pipeline

```
@Library('my shared library')

pipeline {
    // ...
    stages {
        stage {
            steps {
                script {
                    f = new File("foo.txt")
                    libFn(myFile: f)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### The Jenkins Shared Library

```
// ./vars/libFn.groovy
@Grab("3rd party java library")
import LibraryClass

def call(Map params) {
    LibraryClass libraryClass = new LibraryClass();
    libraryClass.processFile(params.myFile);
}
```

### The 3rd Party Java Library

```java
public class LibraryClass {
    public void processFile(File file) {
        // do something with a file
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it exists at all when you create it that way? See -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784194/can-not-create-file-via-groovy-codeor-java-code-in-jenkinsfile-of-a-pipeline-j/48798530#48798530